# Failling to Fit a CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have this train,test shapes:

[image]

My model is:

```
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))  # X_train.shape[1] = No. of Columns
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and then i try:

```
#train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3)
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_7_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (25000, 500)
```

Please, i am on this problem for hours and cant fix it.  Anyone available to help me?

Comment: your X_test is (n_sample, 500) and not (n_sample, 216, 1)

Comment: `Conv1D` expects `3+D tensor` with shape: `batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`.